# How to get a "CB" sound on a microphone

Tags: audio-recording, vocals, voice-manipulation

I'm recording a track and the singer wants to get a real dirty sound on the vocals, like a static-y CB radio almost. I've seen some live acts get a decent sound by talking / singing through a toy battery-powered megaphone into the mic, but I'm wondering if there's an effect or processor or something I can apply to the channel to get that sound.

An example is this guy in the beginning and at 1:55

Another example (looks like using a pedal?) at about 28 seconds into this

Comment: Speakerphone https://www.audioease.com/speakerphone/index.php is the way to go but it's not cheap.

Comment: Speakerphone is the acknowledged best at this, but just google 'vst radio effect'

Comment: Are you looking for something to use live on stage, or in a recording studio during mixing?

Comment: @ToddWilcox just for recording at this point. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

An easy and inexpensive method that is commonly used is an [Impulse Response processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response#Practical_applications), such as [Ableton](https://www.ableton.com/en/packs/convolution-reverb/), [TC Electronics Impulse Pedal](https://www.tcelectronic.com/product.html?modelCode=P0EBH), [Voxengo VST plugin](https://www.voxengo.com/product/pspace/) or the [SciPy Signal Processing API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html).

The IR is especially good at modeling rooms and speakers, even small tinny speakers; such as found on a toy or CB Radio. It is sometimes called lo-fi audio: [KVR Audio Forums](https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=486855),

Tall Guy Films - Make Your Audio Old-Timey/LoFi - AudioThing Speakers:

[Video - TC Impulse Response Loader effects pedal](https://youtu.be/tRY1f97Zgro?t=57)

You can upload some audio to ["VoiceChanger.io Online"](https://voicechanger.io) and choose "Megaphone" (lower right) to produce a similar sound to what you are asking for without having to purchase or install anything.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's go back in time when CB amateur radio was introduced. This was your signal chain:

- speak inside a (small) room, like inside a car // comb-filter
- transmit with quite limited bandwidth
- use high compression many times
- receive with limited bandwidth
- listen to a tiny speaker // comb-filter

**Comb-filter** effects arise from sound waves traveling different routes to the same spot, resulting in a difference in wavelength, resulting in amplification or anihilation. Just have a look at the [drawings](https://www.dpamicrophones.de/mikrofon-universitaet/die-grundlagen-zum-kammfilter-effekt-und-wie-man-ihn-vermeidet) or listen to the audios. This is one major effect for this nasal and often hollow sound just look at the comb filters characteristics).

**Bandwidth**: try a low-pass with about 1.2 - 2.5 kHz, roughly; or replace it by a bandpass, to cut away some of the low frequencies, too, to emphasize the higher ones when listening.

**Compression**: It's basically a non-linear transfer characteristic, so you'll add a lot of distortion, hence overtones. Make sure, to suppress higher components enough by the filter.

So a **simple setup** looks like this:

- comb-filter (first set of parameters)
- compression (second set of parameters)
- bandpass (say ~200 Hz - 1.5 kHz, roughly) (third set of parameters)

This should give you enough complexity to vary sound and approximate what your videos show.

---

**P.S.**: Short verification, using Ardour and Calf plugins with Linux

- right upper: signal chain Fader, comb filter, compressor, lowpass
- most important: comb filter
- lowpass to single out the singer
- almost irrelevant : compressor (bypassed)

Lower left shows you some impression of a comb filter. Set the two parameters, so it sounds a bit artificial, as wanted. Varying these two parameters while playing result in a phaser- or flanger-like sound.

Tuning the lowpass (lower right) close to the transmission limit of CB-radio, while introducing some resonance. This way focus on the singer is even more increased.

So with these 6 parameters (2 from comb filter, 4 from filter) a wide range of sound manipulation is possible, which your DAW can further automate, if needed.

[image: screenshot]